# Code crashing during initialization of NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to initialize `NsmutableAttributedString` with a string productDesc, but the code **crashes** in the line

```
 attrStrInfoLabel= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:productDesc];
```

with error `[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]`.

Please advice my code is

```
NSMutableAttributedString  *attrStrInfoLabel;
  NSMutableString *productDesc;
  productDesc = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"PRODUCT DESCRIPTION:%@",         [productDescription  objectAtIndex:i]];
  attrStrInfoLabel= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:productDesc];
```

Comment: the code crashes in the line attrStrInfoLabel= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:productDesc]; with error [NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]

Comment: Can you print "productDesc" and tell us what is [productDescription  objectAtIndex:i]

Comment: The code you post works, as long as the `productionDescription` array contains an `NSString` and `i` is not out-of-range.  Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: productDescription is an array and the content of productDesc content after that line is @"PRODUCT DESCRIPTION:By accident or accidental collision or overturning consequent upon mechanical breakdown or consequent upon wear and tear,By fire or external explosion or self ignition or lightning or thunderbolt"

Comment: -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc774820
2014-04-29 13:51:15.573 Zeus[2063:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc774820'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out using NSAttributedString instead of NSMutableString.
Take a look at below Code Sample.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attrStrInfoLabel = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
 NSAttributedString *productDesc = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"PRODUCT DESCRIPTION:%@",[productDescription  objectAtIndex:i]];
[attrStrInfoLabel appendAttributedString:productDesc];
```

Meanwhile check the data in productDescription too. Put some check whether is !nil and has count>0.

Comment: Could you explain how your code fixes the issue in the OP's code?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't explain anything.  How does your code fix the issues in the OP's code?

Comment: From Doc : [An NSAttributedString object manages character strings and associated sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string.] As the OP has not posted any stacktrace its difficult to get the exact reason of crash by looking at the above OP's question. There may be possibility that the data at "[productDescription  objectAtIndex:i]" may have some different content.

Comment: Sure, but I think your code is simply a different way to do the same thing, so I don't understand the point of it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not cause the error, but I am going to *assume* you have an `NSLog()` call in the following line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", attrStrInfoLabel);
```

which should be changed to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [attrStrInfoLabel string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise it and then append.

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str appendString:YOUR_STRING];
```